# Access instance variable from one instance to another

Tags: python, oop

I am learning python. Suppose I have my Class named `Dog`, and two instances named `Fido` and `Molly`. I want to change an attribute of second instance by overloading `+` operator with `__add__` so when I type `Fido+Molly`
the `Molly.touched` attribute will be set. How is accessing from one instance to another instance's attributes deployed in python?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are interested in how the [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) special method works.  In essence it works as `x.__add__(y)` where `x` and `y` can be instance objects.  See an example of it's implementation [here](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/04/modifying-add-method-of-python-class.html).

You would need to overload `__add__()` in `Dog` to return something that updates the `y.touched` attribute.  Example:

```
class Dog(object):

    def __init__(self, touched):
        self.touched = touched

    def __add__(self, other):
        other.touched = other.touched + self.touched 
        #return None                                    # optional, explicit

fido = Dog(1)
molly = Dog(2)

fido + molly
molly.touched
# 3
```

Comment: `return None` is redundant, by the way.

Comment: Yes, but it is explicit for someone unfamiliar with Python.  I will make a comment